# IPC_NOWAIT semop() Buffer SysV Processes

Tags: c, process, ipc, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm really in trouble with this piece of code.
I have a buffer and a method Produce() which should be Non Blocking,this means that when many processes try to Produce() all of them should return/or fail except one process.

I read that in man semop(),when we use **IPC_NOWAIT** process should fails if the semaphor is already in use. But What Does it mean fails? It returns something? It does an Exit() ?
I really don't know what happens.

In my code, sometimes I found 2 messages in the buffer and sometimes 1.
Since I'm using IPC_NOWAIT I should have at the end just 1 single message in the buffer because other processes should fail because the have been started together!

Here is the `Produce()` code:

```
msg_t* put_non_bloccante(buffer_t* buffer, msg_t* msg){

    ...

    struct sembuf sb;
    sb.sem_flg=IPC_NOWAIT;


    int x=0;


    sb.sem_num=VUOTE; sb.sem_op=-1;
    if ((x=semop(buffer->semid, &sb,1))<0) {
        printf("\n DENTROOOO DOWN%d VUOTE \n",x);/* down(VUOTE) */
        perror("semop() producer down(VUOTE)");
        exit(-9);
    }

    sb.sem_num=USO_D; sb.sem_op=-1;
    if ((x=semop(buffer->semid, &sb,1))<0) {  /* down(USO_D) */
        printf("\n DENTROOOO DO%dWN USO D \n",x);
        perror("semop() producer down(USO_D)");
        exit(-10);
    }


    if((buffer->msg_presenti)< (buffer->size)){

        /*HERE DROP THE MESSAGE IN THE BUFFER IF IS NOT FULL*/

    }

    sb.sem_num=USO_D; sb.sem_op= 1;
    if (semop(buffer->semid, &sb,1)<0) {  /* up(USO_D) */
        printf("\n DENTROOOO UP USO D \n");
        perror("semop() producer up(USO_D)");
        exit(-11);
    }


    sb.sem_num=PIENE; sb.sem_op= 1;
    if (semop(buffer->semid, &sb,1)<0) {
        printf("\n DENTROOOO UP PIENE \n");/* up(PIENE) */
        perror("semop() producer up(PIENE)");
        exit(-12);
    }

         int delay;
    delay = (int)(random() % 5 ) / 2 + 1;
    sleep(delay);



    }

        shmdt(buffer);
        shmdt(sa);
        shmdt(array_msg); */

    return msg;
}
```

Here my simple CUNIT test:

```
void test_bufferVuoto_3P_NonBlocking_Concurrently(void)
{
    pid_t pid=-1;
    msg_t* msg = msg_init_string("ciao");
    pid_t cons_pid[3];
    buffer_t* b=buffer_init(3);
    int k;


    for(k=0;k<3 && pid!=0;k++) {
        pid = cons_pid[k]=fork();
    }
    switch(pid){
    case -1:
        printf("error fork()");
        exit(-5);
        break;
    case 0:
        buffer_attach(b->bufferid);
        msg_attach(msg->msg_id);
        put_non_bloccante(b,msg);
        msg_deattach(msg);
        buffer_deattach(b);
        sleep(17);
        exit(-5);
    }

    sleep(12);
    int j=0;
    for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
        kill(cons_pid[j],SIGKILL); // ... and Kill processes
        wait(NULL);
    }

    CU_ASSERT_EQUAL(b->msg_presenti,1);
    CU_ASSERT(0==strcmp("ciao", (b->array_msg[0])->content)  );


    msg_destroy_string(msg);
    buffer_destroy(b);

    return;
}
```

I also read a BUG In the Man of SemOP() and IPC_NOWAIT I don'know if is related to this:
*This is however undesirable since it  could  force
       process  termination  to  block  for arbitrarily long periods.  Another
       possibility is that such semaphore adjustments could be  ignored  alto‐
       gether  (somewhat  analogously  to failing when IPC_NOWAIT is specified
       for a semaphore operation).  Linux adopts a third approach:  decreasing
       the  semaphore  value  as  far as possible (i.e., to zero) and allowing
       process termination to proceed immediately.
       In kernels 2.6.x, x <= 10, there is a bug that  in  some  circumstances
       prevents a process that is waiting for a semaphore value to become zero
       from being woken up when the value does actually become zero.  This bug
       is fixed in kernel 2.6.11.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see the semaphores are doing what you ask but your concept of what should be happening is a little skewed.

If you use IPC_NOWAIT and the process can't acquire the semaphore then it will immediately return with -1 and errno == EAGAIN.  Normally you would use this time to do something else and try again later.  You are immediately exiting the process, possibly while holding one or more of the semaphores.

Worse yet it looks like you have at least 3 semaphores going.  You decrement VUOTE and USO_D, do something, and then increment USO_D and PIENE leaving VUOTE locked.  Is that a typo, a mistake, or my misunderstanding?

Overall your expectations of what should happen are wrong.  It is entirely possible for your code to end up with 1,2 or 3 messages.  (And possibly 0 if bailing out while holding a semaphore.)  In other words, depending on how they are scheduled by the OS all 3 of your processes can acquire the semaphore and succeed or maybe just one or two.  It is indeterminate.

If it is *really* your intention that one and only one process can succeed then just initialize a semaphore to 1 and never increment it.  The first process to acquire it will get to proceed and the rest will fail because it will never again allow anything else through.

**Edit**

```
if ((x = semop(buffer->semid, &sb, 1)) < 0)
{
    printf("\n DENTROOOO DOWN%d VUOTE \n", x); /* down(VUOTE) */
    perror("semop() producer down(VUOTE)");
    exit( -9);
}
```

Here *the `semop` call* returns immediately setting x to -1 and errno to EAGAIN if it can't get the lock.  *You* are coding it to just exit the process.  You can code the condition to do something else.

```
if ((x = semop(buffer->semid, &sb, 1)) < 0)
{
    if (errno == EAGAIN)
        return NULL;  //OR WHATEVER you think appropriate
    else
    {   //some other failure that's not EAGAIN
        printf("\n DENTROOOO DOWN%d VUOTE \n", x); /* down(VUOTE) */
        perror("semop() producer down(VUOTE)");
        exit( -9);
    }
}

//ELSE you got the lock
```

The processes don't know about each other except (indirectly) through the use of the semaphores.  Each of them is going to execute this code.  Some will succeed and some won't.

The reason this doesn't work with IPC_NOWAIT is because it is entirely possible each process won't have to wait for the lock.  Depending on how they are scheduled one might get the lock and execute, then the next and the next.  Or some will and some won't.  It is impossible to predict.

Comment: thank you for answering.Firstly, the setting of semaphores is ok,VUOTE is an N-semaphor (means N Locks).Everything works perfectly without the IPC_NOWAIT flag. the problem is that I need to do use it to implement a Non-blocking version. you said:"the process can't acquire the semaphore then it will immediately return with -1 and errno == EAGAIN" but WHAT returns? the entire process? It jumps all the code? or semop() returns? and what value?
Let's suppose that all the sempaphores are locked,What happens at the line :" if ((x=semop(buffer->semid, &sb,1))<0) {" for other processes???

Comment: thank you again. But Since you said that
"if ((x = semop(buffer->semid, &sb, 1)) < 0)" returns -1 
It should do the exit()!! exit means that the process will stop immediately! So why It produces The Message and Not exit() !!!

Comment: @user244050, *Because it didn't fail*. It got the lock.  That's what I have been trying to explain.  It is entirely possible that all 3 of your processes will get the lock and write the message.  There is *nothing* stopping proc1 from getting the lock and writing.  Then proc2 comes along, gets the lock and writes.  Then proc3.  There is *no guarantee* all 3 will try to aquire the lock at the same time and that is the *only* time they will fail - when some other process already has the lock.

Comment: You said:"the process can't acquire the semaphore then it will immediately return with -1 " 
They may acquire all the Lock on VUOTE since is an N-Semaphor but ONLY one Process should acquire the Lock on USO_D since is a binary semaphor!!

Comment: Yes, one process will acquire the binary sem *at a time*.  If a second process tries to acquire it *while* the first has it then the 2nd will fail with EAGAIN. But if the 2nd proc tries to acquire it *after* the first has unlocked it then the 2nd will succeed and write. You aren't understanding the scheduling of the OS slices involved.  Just because you started 3 processes at the same time does *not* mean they are all going to be scheduled at the same time and reach the lock at the same time.

Comment: IF "if ((x = semop(buffer->semid, &sb, 1)) < 0)" returns -1 It should  enter in the code below! because the conditione is true! "(-1 is < 0)"
so all other process should do the exit().
The unique Process which acquire the LOCK since is a Binary-Semaphor(which means that only 1 process can acquire the lock) so ,in this case ""if ((x = semop(buffer->semid, &sb, 1)) < 0)" will return 0 !! and It will not enter below and It should continue,producing the message.@Duck

Comment: Ok!!!! Now I see !!! So How can I make this more Probable?
I should put a long sleep() between the forks! Could you help me? Thank you ! I thought that whena fork() is performed all processes immediatly start!!

Comment: Well I have kind of lost track of what you are doing.  I think you want all 3 processes to try the lock but only 1 to write.  The easiest (and I think most sensible) thing to do is keep a switch in shared memory.  The first process that gets the lock sets the switch.  The other processes will either fail to get the lock and return immediately *or* get the lock, check the switch, unlock and return.  Then only one process gets to write and none of the processes block.